# permissions issue accessing a file

Tags: linux, permissions, command, centos

I log in as root and I issue the following command:

```
ls -l /home/osr/public_html/include/connect.php
```

and I receive

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 osr epanagio 578 Jul 10  2012 /home/osr/public_html/cti/include/connect_to_md5.php
```

This tells me that "osr" and "epanagio" can access the file for read-write-execute.

Now I log in as "epanagio" and I issue the same command:

```
ls -l /home/osr/public_html/include/connect.php
```

and I receive

```
/bin/ls: cannot access /home/osr/public_html/include/connect.php: Permission denied
```

WHAT?! I am "epanagio" and according to the permissions I have rwx to this file.

I am using CentOS and I am obvioulsy lost. 
Can someone PLEASE explain this to me?

Comment: `/home/username` usually have `700` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have the rights to read a file doesn't mean you can actually **REACH** that file. You need permissions to access all of the parent directories of wherever that file is.

Consider it the equivalent of giving you permissions take a $1 bill from me, but that $1 bill is inside a safety deposit box in a bank's vault. You have the rights to the money, but no rights to walk into the vault and open the box.

Comment: Perfect! I checked the permissions and I found that
"nobody" owned a directory in the path. SOLVED!